Should I explicitly close Redis connections if the application crashes?
Suppose I am using some library of any language (Let's say Python) to use in a web application. So, that client has a certain number of connections. Now suppose that for some reason, the application crashes (the container needs to be restarted or something), at that point, would the responsibility of closing those connections be on the operating system? Does this work fine, or should I explicitly close the connections in case the application crashes?
